# How do I solve the 403 Forbidden when opening symfony2 installation on aws error?

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I actually used the EBCLI to upload it directly from the git repository, health status is green on aws console.

Edit: I added "/web/" to the config in aws which seemed to fix it. Not sure I understand why since I already had webroot set as "/web" in parameters.yml

Answer (score 0):

I added "/web/" to the config in aws which seemed to fix it. Not sure I understand why since I already had webroot set as "/web" in parameters.yml